# No .ssh directory when adding a new user

Tags: linux

CentOS 5.3

I have added a new user by doing the following:

```
useradd -m jobBlogs
```

It creates the home directory with initial files. However, when I do the following

```
ls -a
```

there is no .ssh directory.

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add .ssh to /etc/skel by giving mkdir .ssh

Comment: The reason I asked was because when I was trying to log in without the password using ssh. As I moved my id_rsa.pub file to the .ssh directory and renamed it authorized_keys. However, it still asked for my password.

Comment: Have you checkde the sshd log file? If key based auth was attempted but failed this is likely to contain an indication of the problem. The usual issue is access permissions on `.ssh` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` being slacker than required for security purposes (try `chmod 0700 ~/.ssh; chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if this appears to be the case).

Comment: what do you mean "by giving mkdir .ssh" ? ? ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something but.. Why would there be a .ssh directory inside a newly-created home? ^^;

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems in 2 of the servers which should allow password-less ssh, while I was working at it.

Then I had created the directory manually under the $HOME, but the ssh still asked for the password. Then as mentioned by David Spillett, it was the permission problem. Changed the permission of the .ssh directory to 700 and it worked like charm.

Thanks David Spillett.